# How to delete an image in Tkinter Text Widget?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-text

I'm trying to display an image until a user presses a backspace button which would delete the last displayed image. The image is appear alongside text. Here is my code for displaying the image:

```py
im = Image.open(fn)
im_width, im_height = im.size
scale_factor = im_height / 24  # 18 pt font is 24 px
im = im.resize((math.ceil(im_width//scale_factor), math.ceil(im_height//scale_factor)))
emoji_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im, master=self.root)
self.textbox.image_create(tk.END, image=emoji_im)
```

Also, here is how to "backspace" button works for the text components:

```py
self.textbox.delete("end-2c")
```

I couldn't find any good resources for how to remove an image from a text widget. I'm think of trying to use the canvas object instead, but the Text widget is much more intuitive for typing with text.

EDIT: sorry folks here is what self.textbox is:

```py
self.textbox = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.root, height=3, width=30, font=("DejaVu Sans", 18), relief=tk.FLAT,bg='linen', padx=10, pady=10)
self.textbox.place(x=20, y=150)
self.textbox.insert('1.0', '')
```

I tried using the delete method mentioned above used for the text parts, but it doesn't work for the images for some reason.

Comment: Is `self.textbox` a `Label`?

Comment: @adityanithariya It seems like `textbox` is probably a `Text` widget, but OP should really [edit] this question to include the definition of `textbox`, at the very least

Comment: @JRiggles Definitely, it needs an edit

Comment: The answer is to use the `delete` method, passing the index of the image. If that isn’t working for you, please create a [mcve] that illustrates what you’ve tried.

Comment: @BryanOakley thanks for your comment. I edited my post cause it wasn't clear. I tried to use the delete method, but it is not working for the images and I can't find any other resource of how to delete an image, so I'm not sure what else to try and am looking for advice.

Comment: `.image_create()` returns an unique identifier which can be used as index in `.delete()`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible way with standard Tkinter Text widget.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

win = tk.Tk()
im = Image.open("your_image.png")
emoji_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im, master=win)

def add_img():
    textbox.image_create(tk.END, image=emoji_im)
    
def remove_img():
    textbox.delete("end-2c")
    
textbox = tk.Text(win)
textbox.grid()

b_add = tk.Button(win, command=add_img, text="Add Img")
b_add.grid()
b_remove = tk.Button(win, command=remove_img, text="Delete Img")
b_remove.grid()

win.mainloop()
```

This is how you delete an image by text index, there is another way by deleting what image_create returns.

Comment: Thank you for this example!!! Definitely is a good sanity check that this method should work. I'm thinking the issue might be with my placement of the .mainloop() I just started using tkinter so probably a simple rookie mistake

Comment: @chocosunn: that is why we ask for a _complete_ [mcve]